# p:repeat inside of p:dashboard to iterate over panels

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I use PF 5.3.5 and Mojarra 2.2.8. I am migrating an `ice:panelPositioned` component to Primefaces.

```
<p:dashboard id="dashboard" model="#{customAttributesSettings.model}" disabled="#{!customAttributesSettings.editable}" styleClass="positionPanelContainer positionPanelBox positionedPanelBoxR">
   <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{customAttributesSettings.changed}" update="@form" />
   <p:repeat var="column" value="#{customAttributesSettings.availableColumns}" offset="" size="" step="" varStatus="">
      <p:panel id="locked" header="Locked">
         <p:selectBooleanCheckbox partialSubmit="true" value="#{column.selected}" disabled="#{!customAttributesSettings.editable}" valueChangeListener="#{customAttributesSettings.selectionMade}" />
         <h:outputText value="#{column.name}" style="width: 200px;" disabled="#{!customAttributesSettings.editable}" styleClass="columnName#{column.selected ? '' : 'Dis'}" />
         <p:inputText partialSubmit="true" value="#{column.type.width}" disabled="#{!customAttributesSettings.editable}" />
      </p:panel>
   </p:repeat>
</p:dashboard>
```

I get this error

> com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException
>   Error Rendering View[/secure/settings/settings.xhtml]
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.component.repeat.UIRepeat
>   cannot be cast to org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel at
>   org.primefaces.component.dashboard.DashboardRenderer.findWidget(DashboardRenderer.java:96)

There is a discussion about required attributes for `p:repeat` component.
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1627

It does not work with the JSF classic `ui:repeat` component.
How shall I do it, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `p:dashboard` has (unfortunately) no knowledge of how to process a `ui:repeat` as a child. You should use a `c:forEach` for this instead of a `ui:repeat`. The `c:forEach` runs at view build time and create the panels so at render time the `p:dashboard` only sees panels. See Use a c:foreach...See [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: SOLVED IT BY
<c:forEach var="column" items="#{customAttributesSettings.availableColumns}">

Comment: We see questions like this multiple times a day. I've started a documentation topic (request). If I can find some time this evening I'll create a first revision. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsf/topic-requests/6074

Comment: @JasperdeVries: Don't you think the duplicate is already fully describing that? I can 'create' the documentation topic for you, but just wonder what it should/would contain that is not already in the duplicate

Comment: Isn't that the same for all documentation topics? There are a lot of questions covering a lot of topics. I hope that having documentation on this subject makes it easier to find. Same goes for passing parameters in some form.

Comment: Documentation is funny for code examples/snippets, but for Q&A? We already have a platform for that ..